# How would I solve the following convex optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:iso_exp}
\begin{array}{ll}
\underset{q}{\operatorname{minimize}} & (\rho-a) \circ (q - \mu) + (q - \mu)^Tb(q - \mu)\\
\text { subject to } & A(q - \mu) + c = 0, q - \mu \geq 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Everything except $q$ is a constant or a constant matrix/vector. $q$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, and each $q_{ij}$ is a variable. $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.

I'm unsure of how to solve this. I'm trying to fit KKT conditions to this but I can't comprehend those. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hadamard product gives a matrix. What do you mean by minimizing a matrix?

Comment: The question provides no information on the problem or solution attempts. There is high risk that it will be closed as missing context.